# How to boot Tryton server automattically

Tags: python, server, sh, tryton

(I have searched and didn't fine what i was looking for)

Recently I installed GNU Health using Ubuntu 14.04.3 following the wikibooks tutorial. Everything worked as expected. But i have to boot up the Tryton server manually every time i start/restart ubuntu. (as given in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_Health/Installation#Booting_up_the_Tryton_Server ). 
I was wondering if there any way to make it boot automatically at system startup. A script was found in a site but that seemed to be outdated and didn't work. Is there any application or script to boot the server automatically? so that i can use the machine as server without any screen/keyboard/mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific tryton question but more ubuntu question. You need setup init script and install it to System-V scripts.

Puts this script to /etc/init.d/tryton-server file, replace DEAMON variable with your trytond path, check other variables. Then run **update-rc.d tryton-server defaults** command.

```
  #!/bin/sh
  ### BEGIN INIT INFO
  # Provides:             tryton-server
  # Required-Start:       $syslog $remote_fs
  # Required-Stop:        $syslog $remote_fs
  # Should-Start:         $network postgresql mysql
  # Should-Stop:          $network postgresql mysql
  # Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
  # Default-Stop:         0 1 6
  # Short-Description:    Application Platform
  # Description:          Tryton is an Application Platform serving as a base for
  #                       a complete ERP software.
  ### END INIT INFO
  PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
  DAEMON="[REPLACE WITH YOUR trytond PATH]"
  test -x "${DAEMON}" || exit 0
  NAME="trytond"
  DESC="Tryton Application Platform"
  DAEMONUSER="tryton"
  PIDDIR="/var/run/${NAME}"
  PIDFILE="${PIDDIR}/${NAME}.pid"
  LOGFILE="/var/log/tryton/${NAME}.log"
  DEFAULTS="/etc/default/tryton-server"
  CONFIGFILE="/etc/${NAME}.conf"
  DAEMON_OPTS="--config=${CONFIGFILE} --logfile=${LOGFILE}"
  # Include tryton-server defaults if available
  if [ -r "${DEFAULTS}" ]
  then
    . "${DEFAULTS}"
  . /lib/lsb/init-functions
  # Make sure trytond is started with configured locale
  if [ -n "${LANG}" ]
  then
    LANG="${LANG}"
    export LANG
  set -e
  do_start ()
    if [ ! -d "${PIDDIR}" ]
    then
      mkdir -p "${PIDDIR}"
      chown "${DAEMONUSER}":"${DAEMONUSER}" "${PIDDIR}"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
      --chuid ${DAEMONUSER} --background --make-pidfile \
      --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}
  do_stop ()
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} --oknodo
  case "${1}" in
    start)
      log_daemon_msg "Starting ${DESC}" "${NAME}"
      do_start
      log_end_msg ${?}
      ;;
    stop)
      log_daemon_msg "Stopping ${DESC}" "${NAME}"
      do_stop
      log_end_msg ${?}
      ;;
    restart|force-reload)
      log_daemon_msg "Restarting ${DESC}" "${NAME}"
      do_stop
      sleep 1
      do_start
      log_end_msg ${?}
    status)
      status_of_proc -p ${PIDFILE} ${DAEMON} ${NAME} && \
      exit 0 || exit ${?}
      N="/etc/init.d/${NAME}"
      echo "Usage: ${N} {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  exit 0
```